# MySQL Query not working on live server

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL Query not working on live server but working on localhost, my code is as follows:

```
 $res=mysql_query("UPDATE ".$table_name." SET item_name='".$name."',item_description='".$item."' ,item_price='".$price."' WHEREid='".$id."'");
```

Comment: What error is displaying?

Comment: bt it is working on my localhost updating everything

Comment: what is the value of `$table_name`?

Comment: alright, check your DB connection if u r getting 500

Comment: it is the table where i want update data

Comment: db connection is right nothing wrong with that

Comment: How do you know that it is the query that produces the error message? 500 is a general internal server error. First provide some more hints as to what the real error is!

Answer (score 2):

is the the missing space after your WHERE clause?

```
WHEREid='".$id......
```

should be

```
WHERE id='".$id.....
```

Comment: but still you need to tell him about `mysqli_*` and `PDO`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Need to add space between `WHERE` and `id`

```
$res=mysql_query("UPDATE ".$table_name." SET item_name='".$name."',item_description='".$item."' ,item_price='".$price."' WHERE id='".$id."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this `WHEREid='".$id."'"` should be `WHERE id='".$id."'"`, add space between `WHERE` and `id` column.

But also suggest you to stop using `mysql_*` extension, its deprecated and closed in PHP 7, use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

**Modified Query:**

```
$query =
  "UPDATE ".$table_name." 
  SET item_name = '".$name."',
  item_description = '".$item."',
  item_price = '".$price."' 
  WHERE id = ".$id;
```